# Invoking AWS Lambda - API Gateway vs direct invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

We are a team of 10 developers, trying to move process intensive jobs from our Rails application on Heroku to AWS Lambda (Java). We are blocked on  deciding whether to invoke lambda functions via API gateway or via AWS Ruby SDK directly. Depending on the use case, we might have to invoke lambda asynchronously as well. Our payload is very small (< 1-2 KB). We are considering direct invocation primarily to maximise execution time. We are looking for pointers here:

1. Is it easy(& faster) for API gateway to verify the IAM role required to invoke lambda ?
2. Is there any significant reduction in latency b/w lambda and API gateway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have stated, adding API Gateway does not improve performance but does add extra overhead.  Use API Gateway if any of the additional feature it provides are useful to you.  If you control the client, can get credentials on the client with permissions to invoke your Lambda functions directly, and don't need/want any of the additional API Gateway features, the go with the Lambda direct invoke.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Can you also confirm if there is any rate limit on direct invocations from SDK ? We will be invoking 1000 AWS Lambda Requests per minute at peak time (execution time 20-30 seconds). Can the SDK handle the throughput ?

Comment: The SDK does not have any built in limitations, but it is subject to the same rate limits as any other Lambda client.  The limits are enforces within Lambda, not by the client.  You'll need to reach out to the Lambda team via AWS support to request a concurrency limit increase.

Comment: But can you get and return a full HTTP response from Lambda without the AWS API Gateway HTTP integration? Can you read and set headers? Could you read a bearer token in a header? Can the Lambda set the HTTP status code?

Comment: The interface for direct Lambda invocation uses a json based request/response model sent over HTTP.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html

Answer (score 6):

Direct lambda calls are faster b/c there's one network hop less. I doubt you can directly compare lambdas/APIG with regard to latency of IAM verification, but we've benchmarked lambda-lambda calls and lambda-APIG-lambda calls, where the lambdas do no work, i.e. simply return the event object. The average timings are as follows:

- lambda-lambda: 27ms
- lambda-APIG: 47ms

So the tax for the extra hop is 20 ms. We use lambda-lambda calls whenever feasible, especially with lambdas we don't want to expose to the world.

Comment: To add on this: API Gateway has some added features: API Key management, throttling and caching (this could speed up things a lot if your use case allows for caching) for example. If you want to use some of those API Gateway is useful.